# eth sent to non address due to 2 missing digits off the end of address, can it be retrieved?

Tags: cpp-ethereum

Etherereum sent to non address due to 2 missing digits off the end of address, can it be retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

At the current time it is not possible to retrieve eth sent to invalid addresses. It is possible in the future that there will be an EIP to address such issues.